# issue in file creation while running topology in remote cluster using storm

Tags: java, apache-storm

I have created a topology which should read from a file and write it to a new file. My program is running properly in local cluster but while submitting in remote cluster i am not getting any error but file is not getting created. below is my code to submit topolgy in remote cluster :-

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
        final Logger logger = LoggingService.getLogger(FileToFileTopology.class.getName());

        try{
        Properties prop =new Properties();
        prop.load(new FileInputStream(args[0]+"/connection.properties"));

        LoggingService.generateAppender("storm_etl",prop, "");
        logger.info("inside main method...." +args.length);

        System.out.println("inside main sys out");

        Config conf= new Config();
        conf.setDebug(false);
        conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING,1);
        TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

            builder.setSpout("file-reader",new FileReaderSpout(args[1]));
            builder.setBolt("file-writer",new WriteToFileBolt(args[1]),2).shuffleGrouping("file-reader");
            logger.info("submitting topology");
            StormSubmitter.submitTopology(args[0], conf, builder.createTopology());


    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("inside catch");
        logger.info("inside catch"+e.getMessage());
        logger.error("inside error", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

I have also used log4j to create my own logfile for my topology, log file gets created but no error in my log file. pls help

Comment: what does the log say? do you have required permission to write into files over the cluster ?

Comment: I am not able to find any error in log.actually i dont know how to debug in cluster please give some idea on this also.Yes i have permission to write into files over cluster

Comment: do you have the storm UI running? you can go to your `STORM_DIR/bin` folder and run `./storm ui`. Once done you will be able to see the UI listening to port 8080 in your browser. See if that gives you any clue.Also you might want to change `conf.setDebug(false);` to `conf.setDebug(true);` in your code to make it more verbose. Also what are the arguments you are passing while running the job?

Comment: solved this issue.issue was my all executors were busy in running other topologies..once you free executors topology runs perfectly..thanx for your reply

Comment: FYI, might want to take a look [here](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Understanding-the-parallelism-of-a-Storm-topology)

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with Hortonworks2.2. This happened because of permissions.

Even if you are submitting to the cluster as Root user, when submitting the storm jar command, it executes as 'storm' user. It can read the file from source, but won't write, because it doesn't have the necessary rights.

Modify the permissions of destination folder where you want to write file with all permissions.

```
chmod 777 -R /user/filesfolder
```

Comment: setting 777 on the filefolder is completely overkill, 775 (or 770) should be completely sufficient. It should be sufficient to just set the correct group permissions. Also this answer currently doesn't help windows-users (the solution might be the same though)